# Need code for 2 step solution

Tags: flash

I am not a coder so please bear with me. I have a flash movie that I want to play for a website intro. It's only a few seconds long and I have put some extra frames inside as a stop of sorts. A) I need a redirect code to go to my main index page which is no biggie I think, but B) If they have already visited this page before, I want them to be able to bypass this flash page all together and go right to my main site. Not only do I need the code, I need to know where to put it...in the flash video, on the page that houses the video? Thanks for your time in advance

Carmine

I am creating all my resources in CS6

Comment: Please share your code so far (I'm assuming AS2, AS3 ? )

Comment: I haven't used any as yet...probably AS3. I've just got an auto play to happen and added extra cells for timing. It's a very simple flash video with like25 sprites in it...sorry...